# Is there a way to compare multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, `room` table, `item` table and `user` table.

item table has column `room_id` and `user_id`

table data example is like this:

| room_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| First Room | 1111 |
| First Room | 2222 |
| Second Room | 1111 |
| Second Room | 2222 |
| Second Room | 3333 |
| Second Room | 4444 |
| Third Room | 2222 |

And I want to find room_id where exactly matching member group

Example:

input: `[11111, 22222]`, output: `First Room`

input: `[22222]`, output: `Third Room`

input: `[11111, 22222, 3333]`, output: `Not Exists`

In MySQL, How can I find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following aggregation approach.  For users `1111` and `2222`:

```sql
SELECT room_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY room_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 2 AND
       SUM(user_id NOT IN ('1111', '2222')) = 0;
```

The count restriction ensures that there are 2 and only 2 users in the room.  The sum restriction makes sure that nobody else besides users `1111` and `2222` are in a matching room.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT room_id
FROM rooms
GROUP BY room_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id) = {sorted CSV list of distinct input values}
```

For example, for (citate) `input: [11111, 22222]` it will be

```sql
SELECT room_id
FROM rooms
GROUP BY room_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id) = '11111,22222';
```